# How can I hide a column using a Select statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms

```
declare @bid varchar(4) = '1007'    

select sr.release_date,
    sr.customer_id,
    sr.customer_name,
    sr.item_id,
    sr.item_desc,
    sr.order_no,
    sr.qty_on_hand,
    sr.release_qty,
    sr.qty_after_released,
    sr.extended_sell,
    sr.enough,
    sr.route_description

from sri_schedule_releases_view as sr

where 
    ((case 
        when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then (select users.contact_id from users where users.delete_flag = 'n' and users.name = 'John')
    end = @bid) or 
    (case 
        when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then (select users.contact_id from users where users.delete_flag = 'n' and users.name = 'Jane')
    end = @bid) or
    (case 
        when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then (select users.contact_id from users where users.delete_flag = 'n' and users.name = 'Doe')
    end = @bid) or
    (sr.contact_id = @bid))

order by sr.item_id asc
```

This query works fine. But I want to display `sr.route_description` only who has the `sr.route_code` **PM 01**, **PM 03** and **PM 05**.

Are there any possibilities to do this?

Comment: Irrelevant but the `where` looks to complicated. It can surely be simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and it works as I expected

```
declare @bid varchar(4) = '1007'    

declare @pm1 varchar(5) = (select users.contact_id from users where users.delete_flag = 'n' and users.name = 'John')
declare @pm3 varchar(5) = (select users.contact_id from users where users.delete_flag = 'n' and users.name = 'Jane')
declare @pm5 varchar(5) = (select users.contact_id from users where users.delete_flag = 'n' and users.name = 'Doe')

if @bid in (@pm1,@pm3,@pm5) 
begin
select sr.release_date,
    sr.customer_id,
    sr.customer_name,
    sr.item_id,
    sr.item_desc,
    sr.order_no,
    sr.qty_on_hand,
    sr.release_qty,
    sr.qty_after_released as available_qty,
    sr.extended_sell as ext_sell,
    sr.enough,
    sr.route_description

from sri_schedule_releases_view as sr

where 
   ((case 
      when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then @pm1
   end = @bid) or 
   (case 
      when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then @pm3
   end =@bid) or
   (case 
      when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then @pm5
   end = @bid) or
   (sr.contact_id = @bid))
end
else
begin
select sr.release_date,
    sr.customer_id,
    sr.customer_name,
    sr.item_id,
    sr.item_desc,
    sr.order_no,
    sr.qty_on_hand,
    sr.release_qty,
    sr.qty_after_released as available_qty,
    sr.extended_sell as ext_sell,
    sr.enough

from sri_schedule_releases_view as sr

where 
   ((case 
      when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then @pm1
   end = @bid) or 
   (case 
      when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then @pm3
   end =@bid) or
   (case 
      when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then @pm5
   end = @bid) or
   (sr.contact_id = @bid))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a `case` statement to your `select` list:

```
declare @bid varchar(4) = '1007'    

select sr.release_date,
    sr.customer_id,
    sr.customer_name,
    sr.item_id,
    sr.item_desc,
    sr.order_no,
    sr.qty_on_hand,
    sr.release_qty,
    sr.qty_after_released,
    sr.extended_sell,
    sr.enough,
    case when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then sr.route_description else '' end as route_description
from sri_schedule_releases_view as sr
where 
    ((case 
        when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then (select users.contact_id from users where users.delete_flag = 'n' and users.name = 'John')
    end = @bid) or 
    (case 
        when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then (select users.contact_id from users where users.delete_flag = 'n' and users.name = 'Jane')
    end = @bid) or
    (case 
        when sr.route_code in ('pm 01','pm 03','pm 05') then (select users.contact_id from users where users.delete_flag = 'n' and users.name = 'Doe')
    end = @bid) or
    (sr.contact_id = @bid))
order by sr.item_id asc
```

Comment: I tried  the same thing but if there are no data in the column, still column heading visible. is there any chance to get rid of the column heading?

Comment: What UI are you using? SMSS?

Comment: yes, version 12.0

Comment: SSMS can't "hide" columns conditionally. You either include the column in your output, and SSMS displays it, or you don't include it in the output. You would need dynamic SQL or conditional logic to achieve the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only show the column if data is present then maybe create a function with two possibilities inside IF statements:

IF data is present
      (Run the normal query)
ELSE
      (copy the same query but without the empty column)

Comment: if I run a query within if statement in a function that query became a sub query. So I cannot retrieve each columns at once

Answer (score 0):

Too much code--just create a temp table with the entire result-set.

```
SELECT * INTO #tmpTbl FROM MyDatabase.dbo.tbl 

ALTER TABLE 

REMOVE columname

SELECT * FROM #tmpTbl 

DROP TABLE #tmpTbl
```

Comment: there might be issues with this approach. if it is an `one off` and a small result set in a not so busy server - maybe - otherwise no